# Matching a value to a column and then outputting a string if a conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mapping

Original question/answer for more context can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284667/matching-values-to-columns-using-specific-range-criteria)

Hello, I am working with a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
data = {
    'Given' : [0.45, 0.39, 0.99, 0.58, None],
    'Year 1' : [0.25, 0.15, 0.3, 0.23, 0.25],
    'Year 2' : [0.39, 0.27, 0.55, 0.3, 0.4],
    'Year 3' : [0.43, 0.58, 0.78, 0.64, 0.69],
    'Year 4' : [0.65, 0.83, 0.95, 0.73, 0.85],
    'Year 5' : [0.74, 0.87, 0.99, 0.92, 0.95]
}
   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

Output:

   Given  Year 1  Year 2  Year 3  Year 4  Year 5
0   0.45    0.25    0.39    0.43    0.65    0.74
1   0.39    0.15    0.27    0.58    0.83    0.87
2   0.99    0.30    0.55    0.78    0.95    0.99
3   0.58    0.23    0.30    0.64    0.73    0.92
4    NaN    0.25    0.40    0.69    0.85    0.95
```

I am assigning the year of "given" and then checking how many years to >=70%. The "given" value is mapped to the lower year if the value is less than 75% of the distance between the two years on either side of "given". I map the "given" column to a "year" column using the following lines:

```
thresholds = df + df.diff(-1, axis=1).abs() * 0.75
below_75 = (df['Given'].to_numpy()[:, None] - thresholds.to_numpy()) < 0
min_year = thresholds.where(below_75).drop(columns=['Given']).idxmin(axis=1).str.replace('Year ', '').astype(float)
min_year = df.where(df > 0.7).drop(columns=['Given']).idxmin(axis=1).str.replace('Year ', '').astype(float) - min_year
```

This works perfectly in most cases, except for in the case where "given" maps to a value already above 70%. In this case, a row such as the following

```
   Given  Year 1  Year 2  Year 3  Year 4  Year 5
0   0.69    0.24    0.5    0.61    0.7    0.74
```

would map to "year 4", and then checks the next column (Year 5) and sees that it is above 0.7, so will output "1" (since it thinks it is 1 year until a value >70%).

But since it is originally mapped to "year 4" which is already above 70%, I would like it to output "done". I feel like this is an extremely easy fix but I am at a loss.

All help appreciated.

Quick summary:

Essentially I am trying to map the "given" value to a "year" column. If the "given" value is <= 3/4 of the way to the next year (i.e. if year 3 is 10%, year 4 is 20%, and "given" is 17%, it would map to year 3 since 17% < 17.5%). Then it calculates how many years until > 70%.

Most of the code was already solved in an earlier question, I am just trying to work on the part of the code that assigns to a specific year.

Comment: Can you better explain the logic? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @mozway essentially I am trying to map the "given" value to a "year" column. If the "given" value is <= 3/4 of the way to the next year (i.e. if year 3 is 10%, year 4 is 20%, and "given" is 17%, it would map to year 3 since 17% < 17.5%). Then it calculates how many years until > 70%.

Comment: 17% of What?? can yu give an example using the first row